# Increment Bitcoin Numerif Format Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, bitcoin

Hello why i try to coding something like a counter for bitcoin. this is the Code

```
result: <div id="counter"></div>
This is the Html
```

This is Javascript Code

```
var INTERVAL = 1; // in seconds

var INCREMENT = (0.00000001).toFixed(8); // increase per tick


var START_VALUE = (0.00000001).toFixed(8); // initial value when it's the start date


var count = 0;


$(document).ready(function() {

 var msInterval = INTERVAL * 3000;
  count = INCREMENT + START_VALUE;

 document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = count;

 window.setInterval( function(){
    count += INCREMENT; 
    document.getElementById('counter').innerHTML = count;
 }, msInterval);

});
```

Heres the Output you can check

https://jsfiddle.net/8eqc2b3t/

Can anyone help

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/bt1d1xjp/

Comment: Thanks man! but how can put this in html file?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I've modified your code a little to make a bit more sense, you're using a few keywords that could be reserved within certain languages, so I'd avoid that in future ( like using `count` as a variable name )

```
var interval = 1; // in seconds
var increasePerTick = (0.00000001).toFixed(8); // increase per tick
var startingValue = (0.00000001).toFixed(8); // initial value
var $counter = $('#counter');
var btcAmount = 0.00000000;

$(document).ready(function() {
    var msInterval = interval * 1000; // Convert to Milliseconds
    $counter.text(startingValue); // Set initial amount

  window.setInterval( function(){
    btcAmount = (parseFloat(btcAmount)+parseFloat(increasePerTick)).toFixed(8); 
        $counter.text(btcAmount);
  }, msInterval);

});
```

The main issue was that when you were using the `+` operand you were adding to the string rather than adding the two floats together. You'd also not added jQuery to your Fiddle, causing it not to work, I've fixed this and shown how to do the calculation here too, which basically is to parse both the floats, set them `toFixed(8)` and then print them to the counter.

The addition part is here:

```
btcAmount = (parseFloat(btcAmount)+parseFloat(increasePerTick)).toFixed(8);
```

You were also converting your `msInterval` incorrectly. Now seconds in interval should work out correctly when changed.

Hope this helps.

### Edit:

Forgot to add the Fiddle, sorry! : https://jsfiddle.net/20Lppogq/

Comment: Hello friend, thanks for the help It was what i was looking for

Comment: @robegland no problem at all, don't forget to accept the answer please! :)

Comment: Ok.  wakeupphate!  help with other think. how can put this in html file?

Comment: for Example thi is part of my all code  '<span class="pending" id="counter" >Earnings : 0.00000000 BTC</span> ' thaths right? and the javascript where i need to put?

Comment: @robegland I think that would probably be a different question you'd need to ask on Stack Overflow, or do a little research on HTML files. You simply just need to add the javascript part to a `.js` file and include it in your page and then put the `result: <div id="counter"></div>`in your `<body>` tag. Just make sure you include jQuery before your script, you can do this by using the jQuery CDN: `https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js`

Comment: @robegland yeah that's about right, you just ned to make sure to read the last part of my last comment there, making sure to include the two JS files.

Comment: I'm very frustrated. I did everything that you told me. But I still can not start the script. I do not want to give up

Comment: @robegland Perhaps you're including the javascript incorrectly, maybe for now just put it in the `<head>` section. Add `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>` then create a new file called `btc_calc.js` in the same directory as your index.html and add `<script src="btc_calc.js"></script>` after the jquery one.